# mysql #1034 - Incorrect key file for table 'orders'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de modificar la estructura de la tabla `orders`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `idOrder` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `addedDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `idSalesRep` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` enum('pending','confirmed','closed','cancelled') CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
  `idWarehouse` tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idCustomer` mediumint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idUser` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idCompany` tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `idShippingVia` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idDelivery` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `updateDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

ALTER TABLE `orders`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idOrder`),
  ADD KEY `idSalesRep` (`idSalesRep`),
  ADD KEY `idWarehouse` (`idWarehouse`),
  ADD KEY `idCustomer` (`idCustomer`),
  ADD KEY `status` (`status`),
  ADD KEY `idUser` (`idUser`),
  ADD KEY `idCompany` (`idCompany`),
  ADD KEY `idShippingVia` (`idShippingVia`),
  ADD KEY `idDelivery` (`idDelivery`);

ALTER TABLE `orders`
  MODIFY `idOrder` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Cuando intento ejecutar una modificación a la estructura

```sql
ALTER TABLE `orders` 
    ADD `partialShipment` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' AFTER `updateDate`, 
    ADD `partialShipMin` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `partialShipment`, 
    ADD `partialShipQty` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `partialShipMin`, 
    ADD INDEX (`partialShipment`);
```

Obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> mysql #1034 - Incorrect key file for table 'orders'; try to repair it

Ya intente:

> ANALYZE TABLE `orders`;
> db_name.orders    analyze status  OK

> CHECK TABLE `orders`;
> db_name.orders    check   status  OK

> OPTIMIZE TABLE `orders`;
> db_name.orders    optimize    note    Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead
> db_name.orders    optimize    status  OK

> REPAIR TABLE `orders`;
> db_name.orders repair note The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair

¿Que puedo hacer para arreglar la tabla?

Comment: ¿exportarla e importarla con otro nombre? ¿copiarla con otro nombre? ¿o siempre te da ese error intentándo eso también? Una vez copiada o importada repite esas alteraciones a ver que ocurre. Por lo que leo por ahí también lo relacionan con falta de espacio en esa partición, revisa a ver.

Comment: Hola @masterguru, gracias por tu comentario. La tabla está en una base de datos en producción, por lo que sería ideal no provocar una caída del servicio. Igual me acabas de dar una idea. Con respecto al espacio, ese no sería el problema, hay de sobra.

Comment: Ojo con eso del espacio, haz un `df -h` para descubrir si la partición de /var es única y separada de la de /home o quizás esté en /. Lo digo porque no sería la primera vez que me he encontrado sobrado de espacio en servidores de hosting, pero las particiones estaban divididas y casi todo estaba destinado a /home y no se tuvieron en cuenta los espacios de /var o / que podrian albergar monstruosas bases de datos, o la propia /tmp, pues podría ser usada para eso quizás

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que los otros campos no son relevantes? Con el EMV que nos compartes el código funciona, creando la tabla así: `CREATE TABLE orders ( idOrder int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, partialShipment tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', partialShipMin smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', partialShipQty tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', KEY partialShipment (partialShipment) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` Considera poner el `CREATE TABLE` completo, pues **todo** es importante en ese sentido.

Comment: También podrias probar con un [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-explain-analyze/) sobre esa consulta a ver si te dice lo que piensa hacer con ella, para estimar los recursos que va a consumir, o simplemente un EXPLAIN (no se si funciona sobre los ALTER, espero que si)

Comment: @A.Cedano, porque según entiendo el problema no está en la estructura, sino que hay algo corrupto en el archivo de la tabla. Si la estructura completa es relevante, el contenido de toda la tabla también y eso si que no lo puedo compartir.

Comment: Es extraño que falle con el `ALTER TABLE`, sería interesante saber si puedes hacer `SELECT` por ejemplo sobre ella y si funciona en esos casos. Viendo la estructura completa (sin los datos) se puede verificar eventuales problemas que podrán resurgir en un futuro, cuando crees que lo tienes resuelto. Sería interesante también verificar el log de errores de MySQL para ir a la raiz del problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano, actualice y puse el export de la estructura completo.

Comment: No veo nada extraño en tu `CREATE TABLE`, salvo que `utf8mb3` es obsoleto y [según el MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html) será sacado de futuras versiones de MySQL. Deberías considerar el paso a `utf8mb4` como sugiere el mismo MR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gracias a @masterguru por su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537384/mysql-1034-incorrect-key-file-for-table-orders-try-to-repair-it#comment952161_537384), llegue a una solución.
Quizás no es la más elegante, pero anduvo.

---

Los pasos que realice para llegar a una solución fueron:

1. Duplique la tabla `orders` (*estructura, indices, contenido, etc.*)

   ```
   CREATE TABLE orders_new LIKE orders; 
   INSERT INTO orders_new SELECT * FROM orders;
   ```
2. Realice los cambios en la nueva tabla.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `orders_new` 
     ADD `partialShipment` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' AFTER `updateDate`, 
     ADD `partialShipMin` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `partialShipment`, 
     ADD `partialShipQty` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `partialShipMin`, 
     ADD INDEX (`partialShipment`);
   ```
3. Renombre las tablas.

   ```
   RENAME TABLE `orders` TO `orders_old`,
     `orders_new` TO `orders`;
   ```

Comment: Perfecto!  Entonces queda descartado el tema del espacio en disco :-)  A saber si habia un problema de bloqueos o vete tu a saber. Confiemos que no se haya perdido nada.

Comment: @masterguru no queda descartado necesariamente... el problema podría estar en la definición misma de la tabla. Será interesante saber si la nueva tabla resiste bien un nuevo `ALTER TABLE` similar o si el problema resurge, en cuyo caso será evidente que quedarán asuntos pendientes de arreglar y que muy probablemente la tabla volverá a dar problemas en el futuro. Marcos, espero que tengas una política de backups, si no la tienes, es el momento de implementarla o podrías perder datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano, gracias por tu comentario. Acabo de probar agregando un campo cualquiera y un índice sobre el nuevo campo y sigue funcionando. Con respecto al backup, si tienen, local y externo.